# Extracting all the variables from a .js file or a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to extract all the input, output and internal variables from a .js file by name and type? If no, then is there a way to extract all the input, output and internal variables from a JavaScript function by name and type?

I would prefer to use anything from the PHP or JavaScript world, but any other method that can be integrated into a PHP page or a JavaScript function would be appreciated.

Edit: my mistake with the variable type. I fogot that it's not relevant in JavaScript.

Comment: There is no mechanism to extract all the input, output, and internal variables from a .js file by name and type. The question doesn't really make sense; JavaScript variables don't *have* a type.

Comment: You can't really get all of the inputs because there's virtually an unlimited number of ways of getting input. Likewise, you can't get all of the output without defining what "output" means (rendered to the DOM, sent to a server, appears in an alert, returned from a function, etc.). You could write a scanner which would give you the names of all of the variable in a JS file and you could attempt to do some type inference to determine their types but since JS isn't statically typed, these would only be approximations.

Comment: well..you can certainly try it like this way that you can read line by line your `js` file through `fopen()` and then you can check in each line that if the line contains word like `var` by using `strpos()` which would say that the line has variables mentioned in it so then you can get your variables like this way..!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all objects with type `function` in your javascript file you can do this directly in `javascript` in the same page

```js
var console = {
  log: function(s) {
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
  }
}

function allfunctions() {
    var myfunctions = [];
    for (var l in this) {
      try {

        if (this.hasOwnProperty(l) &&
          this[l] instanceof Function &&
          !/myfunctions/i.test(l)) {
          myfunctions.push(this[l]);
        }
      } catch (ex) {}
    }
    return myfunctions;
  } //allfunctions

function myFunction1(args) {
  return "foo";
}

function myFunction2(args) {
  return "bar";
}

var allfns = allfunctions();
for (var f in allfns) {
  console.log(allfns[f])
}
```

```html
<div id="console" />
```

Of course, depending on your runtime execution scope, you will get different results, like executing in `Node.js` your scope will be limited by the node process.